# Apply a function/formula to a range in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have many operations to perform on a set of data in excel.  The data is in columns, and the functions are a lot of variations on things like `=(A1*C1/B1)+(A2*C2/B2)+...`

Right now they are spelled out as above in fixed cell notation, but I'd like to do something like `Sum(Range(A*C/B))`  Such that I can increase the number of rows to include in the calculation without having to re-code all the formula.  I have tried just adding columns to contain interim calculations, but there are just too many different formula, so the columns become unwieldy.  In effect I want similar functionality to SUMPRODUCT, except the thing to sum is more complicated than a product.  Is there such a function, and if not, what are good ways to approximate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as an array formula if you know how many rows you're working with. You enter an array formula by typing it out and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and it will display with curly brackets `{ }` around it.

`=SUMPRODUCT(A:An,C:Cn/B:Bn)` where `n` is the last row you're using.

Comment: Interesting.  I think we're on to something, but when I try it, the formula is being re-written `=SUMPRODUCT(A:A4,'C':C4/B:B4)` (note the single quotes around C) and then it shows up with a `#NAME?` error

Comment: Try using A1, C1, and B1 instead of A, C and B. No idea why it would do that.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was.  I took the hint and just named the column ranges, so I don't even have to care how many rows there are.  It ends up being effectively `=Sum(RowA*RowC/RowB)` where RowA, RowB, and RowC are the named ranges.

Comment: As long as it doesn't pull zeros, it will work.